# ERROR! 'copy' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to make ansible playbook that connects to the server via ssh and sends a file.

Most of my google search yield no concrete results.

```
- 
  become: true
  hosts: all
  remote_user: artur
  tasks: ~
- 
  copy: 
    dest: /home/artur/grep_error.py
    group: UnixUsers
    mode: 420
    owner: artur
    src: /Users/artur/Desktop/sublime/projects/scripts/grep_error.py
  name: "example copying file with owner and permissions"
```

I expect to copy the file over to the ssh server.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you are trying to run Ansible from a Windoze host.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. [Take Y minutes to learn yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/). Pay particular attention to the fact that indentation and new lines are syntactically significant
2. Install [yamllint](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and validate your yaml files. It will save you a lot of precious time
3. Install [ansible-lint](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint) and validate your files again. This one will go over the particular ansible syntax and watch for good practice
4. Read the doc about [playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks.html) and make sure you respect the syntax (i.e. understand the errors you get from valiators above).

Now I gave you some references, here is a correction of your playbook

```
---
- name: My first play to copy files
  become: true
  hosts: all
  remote_user: artur

  tasks:

    - name: Example copying file with owner and permissions
      copy:
        src: /Users/artur/Desktop/sublime/projects/scripts/grep_error.py
        dest: /home/artur/grep_error.py
        owner: artur
        group: UnixUsers
        mode: 0420

    - name: I'm just a dummy task to show you a play can go on
      debug:
        msg: I'm a dummy task
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, just had to delete ```become: true``` .